# Keigo form of ~てみる

Tags: verbs, conjugations, て-form, keigo

What is sonkeigo form of verb-て/で+みる?
I've heard somewhere 思い出してごらんになる as a keigo form of 思い出してみる, but I doubt if it's correct.

Comment: Curious as to where you saw/heard or learned to say 「思い出してごらんになる」.　A great question, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be too obvious to OP, but we can use られる and say like this:

- その本{ほん}を読んで{よんで}みられると良い{よい}でしょう。
- 食べて{たべて}みられることをお勧め{おすすめ}します。
- 正直{しょうじき}に言って{いって}みられてはどうですか。

But I recommend that you try to apply honorifics to the main verb (these are more common, and perhaps politer, too):

- その本{ほん}をお読み{およみ}になってみると良い{よい}でしょう。
- 召し{めし}上が{あが}ってみることをお勧め{おすすめ}します。
- 正直{しょうじき}に仰って{おっしゃって}みてはどうですか。

These 二重敬語{にじゅうけいご} examples are not entirely wrong, but are probably frowned upon by some:

- (?) その本{ほん}をお読み{およみ}になってみられると良い{よい}でしょう。
- (?) 召し{めし}上が{あが}ってみられることをお勧め{おすすめ}します。
- (?) 正直{しょうじき}に仰って{おっしゃって}みられてはどうですか。

Answer (score 3):

Honorific form would be 〜てごらんなさる, often used in imperative 〜てご覧{らん}なさい

On the other hand, a person in a higher position talking to a person in a lower position might use a shortened form 〜てごらん, like やってご覧{らん}. Although you add a word in seemingly polite form "ご覧" it would be considered impolite if used toward a teacher or a stranger.

Comment: +1 on the てごらん。I hear this all the time when mothers are speaking to their children.

Comment: 「やってごらん」だけで「やってみろ」の意味になりますね。

Comment: @naruto Thank you for pointing that. Corrected.

Comment: @naruto But I often heard やってみてごらん used for example by a martial arts teacher. Google also returns >80k hits for that phrase. Is it superfluous?

Comment: @macraf やってみてごらん is perfectly valid. やってごらん is the better example in this case, anyway :-)

Comment: @naruto `てごらん` is more forceful, like saying "do it" vs. `てみてごらん` which is more like "try it".